# Change the placeholder for all fields in Magento 2 checkout pages

Tags: magento2

I need to change the placeholder for all fields in the Magento 2 checkout pages. How to implement that?

Please suggest a method to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Magento 2 DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html) explained how to customize Checkout page.

> Step 1: Implement the HTML template for the field

Create a new `<your_template>.html` template in the following directory

```
 <your_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/form/element
```

**Example of a field template**

```
<!-- input field element and corresponding bindings -->
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" />
<!-- additional content -->
<img src="%path_to_image%" alt="image_de"/>
```

> Step 2: Specify the new template in layout

In your custom module directory, create a new `<your_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` file.

In this file, add content similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- the field you are customizing -->
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">%Vendor_Module%/form/element/%your_template%</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 3: Clear files after modification

1. Delete all files in the `pub/static/frontend` and
   `var/view_preprocessed` directories.
2. Reload the pages.

Comment: yes, let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Have you tried above solution ?

Comment: Yeah i have tried. But it's not working.

Comment: replace         placeholder: placeholder

Comment: with         placeholder: label,

Comment: Change placeholder: placeholder to placeholder: label

Comment: remove static content and check again

Comment: Have you checked the above ?

Comment: Yeah i have tried all the methods..But it's not working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83664/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-anand-v).

Comment: PFB the video link in which i had recorded the steps what i did for this checkout page. https://www.screencast.com/t/i9InCPQV7